# I was trying to install glmnet on my Mac (M1 chip), and could not install the package

Tags: r

I looked into install gfortran to see if that can solve my issue, but I don't see exactly how I can go about it. It says it downloaded but I still can't access the package via library(glmnet)

install.packages("glmnet")

(among other things...)

```
In file included from elnet_exp.cpp:2:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:40:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra:51:
/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
18 warnings generated.
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c glmnet5dpclean.f -o glmnet5dpclean.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [glmnet5dpclean.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glmnet’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library/glmnet’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glmnet’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/7z/jd_0l4wd1997924m5_w5nz240000gp/T/RtmpAQ4igM/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: One option is to try the experimental gfortran for M1 silicon release here: https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases

Comment: I second @jared_mamrot's comment. Just letting you know, I am working to replace the Fortran code entirely and am almost done. We will soon release a version of glmnet that only depends on C++ backend, so this problem will naturally go away - so be on the lookout for that!

Answer (score 0):

download gfortran11 from [here](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/11-arm-alpha2)

then

```
sudo mv YOURPATH/gfortran /opt/R/arm64/
```

if you have installed gfortran12, rename or remove it